# $φ^3$ scalar field one-loop diagram calculation via dimensional regularization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-regularization

I have been trying to understand how to compute the following loop diagram in $\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3$ theory, with $m\neq0$ and I am not getting anywhere. From what I understood I am supposed to calculate it using a process called dimensional regularization, which I have understood in theory but cannot apply it in the current situation. The integral I get from the diagram is $$\int \frac{1}{k^{2}+m^{2}} \frac{1}{\left((p+k)^{2}+m^{2}\right)} d^{D} k.$$

[image: One-loop diagram in \phi^3 theory]

Comment: Perhaps this will help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the dimensional regularization scheme, you have to work out the original integrand via the Feynman parameter trick, that is
$\frac{1}{A B} = \int_0^1 dx \frac{1}{[A + (B - A) x]^2}$
where:
$A = (p + k)^2 + m^2$
$B = k^2 + m^2$

Then you complete the square as $[(k + \cdot \cdot \cdot)^2 - \Delta]^2$, next you shift $k^\mu \to k^\mu + \cdot \cdot \cdot$, the measure $d^dk$ being unchanged, and you get an expression to which you can apply the dimensional regularization. In this case
$\int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{(k^2 - \Delta)^2} = \frac{i}{(4 \pi)^{d/2}} \frac{1}{\Delta^{2 - d/2}} \Gamma (2 - d/2)$

Then you expand as $d = 4 - \epsilon$, with $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: That was great help! Thanks a lot! I only had a hard time trying to find the renormalization constants. I'll get back to it!