# $φ^3$ theory: three-point, one-loop diagram ($D=4$)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration

I am attempting to calculate the one-loop diagram for the $φ^3$ three-point function, which is equal to (dropping a factor of $-i$): $$g^3 \int_E \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^4} \frac{1}{(k+q)^2+m^2} \frac{1}{(k-p)^2+m^2} \frac{1}{k^2+m^2} \,d^4k.$$
After completing the square for the integrated momentum and using Feynman parameterisation, we eventually get: $$\frac{g^3}{16 \pi ^2} \int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{1}{x y q^2+\left(1-z+z^2\right) m^2}\delta (1-x-y-z)dxdydz.$$
I'm having some trouble computing this final integral.

Comment: Why does the loop consist of 3 propagators ? This looks more like 2-loop.

Comment: @FredericThomas A loop with three incoming/outgoing particles, with propagators between the vertices.

Comment: Look at this post on $\phi^3$ theory https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579652/%cf%863-scalar-field-one-loop-diagram-calculation-via-dimensional-regularization?rq=1

Comment: @FredericThomas I think I've got the Feynman parameterisation correct, it's just that I'm left over with this integral over those Feynman parameters.

Comment: There is 1 propagator too much in the denominator, also in the first sentence of the Nihar Karve he asks where you got the denominator from. Whatever it is calculated it is very probably not  $phi^3$ one-loop, even if you get the integral well parametrised or not. Because the integral itself is questionable.

Comment: @FredericThomas but I'm looking at the three-point function, not the two-point function which the question you've linked to is concerned with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, how did you get the denominator?
Are there some kinematic conditions on $p^2$ and $(p+q)^2$, which might be related to $q^2$ and $m^2$?
Are you sure about the coefficient in front of $m^2$?

Nevertheless, I would show a way to proceed with your integral:
\begin{equation}
  I \equiv \int_0^1 dx \int_0^1 dy \int_0^1 dz
  \frac{\delta(1-x-y-z)}{x y q^2 + (1 - z + z^2) m^2},
\end{equation}
though I will not go into the detail that will be too cumbersome.
After integrating over $z$ by using the delta function, and subsequently changing the variable $x \to 1 - x$, you get
\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^1 dx \int_0^x dy \frac{1}{A x^2 + B y^2 + C xy + D x + E y + F} ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
A = B = F = m^2, \qquad
C = - (q^2+2m^2), \qquad
D = - m^2, \qquad E = q^2 + m^2 .
\end{equation}
This type of integrals appearing in one-loop calculations was thoroughly studied in the famous [1979 paper by 't Hooft and Veltman](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(79)90605-9).
The denominator is quadratic both in $x$ and $y$, which is rather tough to tackle, so the first step is applying a variable transformation in such a way that the denominator becomes linear in one of the variables. Then performing the integral with respect to the linear variable (with an adequate splitting of the integration domain and variable transformations) gives logarithms, whose arguments are now quadratic in the remaining variable. A quadratic argument can be factorised as a product of two linear terms, so the logarithms with quadratic arguments are split into logarithms with linear arguments. At the end of the day, integrating such logarithms (multiplied with some reciprocals) leads to dilogarithms (known as Spence's functions); indeed many terms with dilogarithms and logarithms in general.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Are you asking about the denominator of the initial integral over momentum or the integral over the Feynman parameters?

Comment: I was wondering about the denominator in the Feynman parameterization, especially the term with the mass squared, $(1-z+z^2) m^2$. The standard formula gives (in general, without using any kinematic conditions for momenta squared and internal masses) $(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_N)^2 m^2 = m^2$ for any scalar $N$-point one-loop integrals with the equal internal mass (see, for example, Eq. (10) of https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4177).

Comment: By the way, if this is just homework, maybe your teacher doesn't expect you to go to the long analytic calculations with dilogarithms. If this is the case, then you can resort to numerical integration (after you confirm the integral is finite).

Comment: Ah, I'm interpreting the diagram as an particle entering with on-shell momentum $p$, leaving with on-shell momentum $p'$ and transferring momentum $q = p - p'$. After completing the square, there's a bit of algebra to get the form in the denominator. I'm just looking at $φ^3$ theory in my own time as part of an attempt to clear up some confusions I have about renormalised QFT. The reason I was interested in this vertex in particular is that I was wondering if it had a divergence as $q^2$ went to zero, and if it did, whether that was a problem.

Comment: OK, if $q = p - p'$ and $p^2 = p'^2 = -m^2$, your Feynman parametrisation looks right. But then in your momentum integration the second propagator has a momentum $k+p$ (not $k-p$), doesn't it? If you are interested in the value of this integral for $q^2 \to 0$, just set $q^2 = 0$ in the Feynman parametrisation: indeed it is (infrared) finite and you can easily compute the value. Divergent one-loop scalar integrals are summarised in [this site](https://qcdloop.fnal.gov/).

Comment: Thanks for a link to that site! You very well may be right that I have the wrong sign for $p$, but I went with what I did due to [Peskin and Schroeder's expression](https://imgur.com/fkwuDnE) for the QED one-loop vertex diagram.

Comment: The picture shows $q = p' - p$, then everything is fine. I think I misunderstood the convention for the momentum directions :-)